# Replacing hash with slash in address bar with Javascript

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, hash, slash

I've got ajax links as the following:

```
www.domain.com/profile#dashboard
```

is it possible to change this via htaccess into:

```
www.domain.com/profile/settings
```

If so, how? :D

**EDIT:**

**This is my loadPages .js file:**

```
(document).ready(function() {

if (location.href.indexOf("#") > -1)
    location.assign(location.href.replace('#', "/"));

    //preload pages
    if(window.location.hash) {
        //Loading
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); //Puts hash in variable, and removes the # character      
        loadContent( hash+".php" );     }   
});


function loadContent(pagina) {
    jQuery("#page").load(pagina);
}
```

**This is my .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Hide de submap pages
RewriteRule ^$ pages/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1

#Hide de logged-in file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ logged-in.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/logged-in\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

**This is how I link pages to open in the #pages div - dashboard page as example**

```
<a class="iconNav" href="#dashboard" id="loadDashboard" onclick="loadContent('dashboard.php');">
```

**I updated my .htaccess file. Now the links look like:**

```
www.domain.com/#dashboard
```

**I want it to be:**

```
www.domain.com/dashboard
```

Comment: URL part after `#` doesn't even reach Apache, it has to be done in Javascript itself.

Comment: I just updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `location.assign ( url )` method to change URL in the browser:

```
if (location.href.indexOf("#") > -1)
    location.assign(location.href.replace('#', "/"));
```

Comment: What URL do you see in the browser when you see 500 error? Can you Apache error.log also for actual reason for 500 error.

Comment: You aren't giving enough info to investigate it better. I asked what URL is it causing 500 error.

Comment: This 500 has nothing to do with this Javascript. Even `http://mijn.dannyhtek.nl/` is also causing 500 error.

Comment: I've edited the .htaccess file and its not returning the 500 error anymore. It loads the dashboard.php page without any stylings eventhough it should have stylings.

Comment: But you've not posted any `.htaccess` that's why I couldn't investigate anything on that front.

Comment: Take a look at my edited question. Should have all the info you need.

Comment: Nope it does not but its not loading the content either.

Comment: I can only help you on what information I have. Question was how to change that Ajax URL and it is changing now. Beyond this I don't have your full code to look inside it.

Comment: you're right about that. I think I'm just going to leave it for what it is. THanks for you effort though.